# How do I change the Title Background color On Windows Platform (Xamarin)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp, xamarin.windows

[Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/riH8h.png) I am developing an application using Xamarin Forms in Visual Studio 2013. I have managed to change the Header Background color for Android but I am failing to do the same for Windows project. It comes with the Default Dark theme. Please Assist me.
Thank You

Comment: You should show us what you tried.

Comment: @476rick On Android i have used a Theme which i referenced in MainActity.cs , but i don't know where to change on the windows platform

Comment: are you putting your page inside a NavigationPage? If so, I believe you can use the NavigationPage.BarBackgroundColorProperty to set that color

Comment: @deckertron_9000 It works, I just needed that...NavigationPage.BarBackgroundColorProperty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NavigationPage.BarBackgroundColorProperty Works! Thank You for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear to me, but I think that this is what you mean. With "Header Background color" I think you mean the background color of the title of a page.

This is the code I use in my Xamarin.Forms application. The code works on Android, iOS and UWP.

```
public class ExamplePage : ContentPage
{
    public ExamplePage()
    {
        Title = "Example Page";
        BackgroundColor = Color.Blue; //Make this any color you like

        Content = null; //put your own content here
    }
}
```

You can specify the color of the background color on every page.

Comment: thank you for your response, i have added a screenshot to the question. I have done what you are suggesting on the PCL but it is not Working

Comment: You want to change the text behind: "Vista Africa Brand Header"? You should post the code of your class.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <StackLayout.BackgroundColor>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Color"
                                    Android="#51C0D4"
                                    WinPhone="#51C0D4"
                                    iOS="#51C0D4"></OnPlatform>
    </StackLayout.BackgroundColor>
```