# How to change the Title bar background color in Xamarin.Forms wpf application?

Tags: wpf, xamarin.forms

I am doing an application in wpf with xamarin.forms in which i need to change the title bar background color to mach with our theme.But by default a blue color background is appearing.Can anyone please help and guide me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I change the Title Background color On Windows Platform (Xamarin)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41722253/how-do-i-change-the-title-background-color-on-windows-platform-xamarin)

Comment: Hi Mark. Thank you for your response.I have used this earlier, but the navigation bar background color is changing.I want to change the Title bar background color which conatains Minimize,maximize and close options.

Answer (score 7):

You have to add these 2 keys in App.xaml:

```
<Application.Resources>
...
      <SolidColorBrush x:Key="CommandBarBackgroundColor" Color="Orange" />
      <SolidColorBrush x:Key="CommandBarTextColor" Color="Blue" />
...
<Application.Resources>
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for!